# Defining malloc array size with scanf and initialising

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, scanf

I'm trying to create a program that asks the user for a size of an array, then asks the user to populate it.

Whenever I launch the program, the "Element %d" printf displays the %d as a large number instead of 1.

If I continue the program after entering the value into the array, the debugger crashes. What's happening here? Did I accidentally place the address in the array position? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int elements = 0;
    printf("How many Elements will you enter?");
    scanf("%d", &elements);

    int* elementArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * elements);
    int i = 0;
    while (elementArray[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("Element %d: ", elementArray[i]);
        scanf("%d", &elementArray[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(elementArray);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Reading the comments, I meant `printf("Element %d: ", elementArray[i]);` was supposed to print one during the first loop. Though I should edit the code to be elementArray[i] + 1 so it doesn't print "Element 0" instead of Element 1. Apologies for the barebones code, it's half finished, I wanted to solve this problem before finishing it off. Will work on the solutions given now. Thanks for the help

EDIT2: Thanks to all of you, especially Sharuya! Here's my finished code.

```
void printArray(int* elemArray, int elements)
{
    printf("The Array contains: ");
    for (int k = 0; k < elements; k++)
    {
        printf("%d,\t", elemArray[k]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int elements = 0;
    printf("How many Elements will you enter?");
    scanf("%d", &elements);

    int* elementArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * elements);

    int input = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < elements; j++)
    {
        printf("Element %d: ", j + 1);
        scanf("%d\n", &input);
        *(elementArray + j) = input;
    }

    printArray(elementArray, elements);

    free(elementArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Only issue now is, between the "Element 1: " and "Element 2: " printf, I get a blank line, that allows me to enter a number, upon submitting, it continues as normal. If I submit an array with 5 elements, It asks me for 6 elements, and only 5 appear... What's happening here?

Comment: Try to print the number of the element, instead of its value. I.e. kill the `elementArray[` and `]`.

Comment: You are not initializing the memory allocated to `elementArray` and you are trying to compare it. It may happen that all the elements are non zero and your loop may be continuing more than the number of elements you have allocated.

Comment: OP, you seem to need to explain the meaning of the "1" you want to print. Some answers below did not get your goal there.

Comment: Also explain the goal of comparing to 0, I guess you want to end when value 0 is entered. Otherwise explain in detail, please.

Comment: Because @MichaëlRoy implies: OP, would you care stating whether this is a homework/challenge question? If yes please read the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know that malloc() function dynamically allocates memory according to the size calculated (with the help of sizeof() ) and returns the address of this memory location.
However this address is not associated with any data type i.e. only a void* pointer can store this address of an incomplete data type.
Thus instead of mentioning

```
int* elementArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * elements);
```

mention and use typecasting to it

```
int* elementArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * elements);
```

As per your code, elementArray is a pointer which will store the address of an integer

```
int *elementArray;

printf("Element %d: ", elementArray[i]);
```

Thus the above line will actually print the address pointed to by the pointer and not the index since incrementing a pointer is same as
elementArray stores the base address.

```
i.e elementArray++ is equal to elementArray+1 == elementArray[1] will point 
to the next memory location after 4 bytes.(since integer is stored in 4 bytes)
```

I have modified  your code correcting your mistakes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int elements = 0;
    printf("How many Elements will you enter?");
    scanf("%d", &elements);

  //the below statement actually allocates contiguous block of memory equal 
  //to no of elements and the pointer points only to first element.
  //Incrementing it will point to next element

    int* elementArray =(int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * elements);  
                               //typecasting of void* pointer to int*
    int i = 0,elm;
    for(i=0;i<elements;i++)                                           
 //Since u know iterations will be equal to no of elements it is better to use for loop
    {
        printf("Element %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &elm);
        *(elementArray+i)=elm;
//Storing the data in elm and making the pointer point to next free 
//dynamically allocated block of memory and using * operator the value at 
//this location is accessed and storing elm value in it
    }

    for(i=0;i<elements;i++)
     printf("%d",*(elementArray+i));

    free(elementArray);

    return 0;
}
```

This code works and I hope it make things clear !!!

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
while (elementArray[i] != '\0')
```

This check is the problem

1. `malloc` gives no guarantee that the memory initialized will be `zero filled`. Hence your loop may cross over the allocated memory and try to read memory that your program is not supposed to read (hence resulting in a crash)
2. If it's zero filled your code will never enter the loop

What you need is

```
while (i < elements)
```

Also `printf` should come after `scanf` for any meaningful result. If you want to just get the index that you are about to enter use `printf("Element: %d", i)` instead of `elementArray[i]`

Comment: I doubt that this solves OPs first problem as stated "Whenever I launch the program, the "Element %d" printf displays the %d as a large number instead of 1.". It does solve other issues though.

Comment: That's because OP is printing uninitialized memory which is UB. He may see a large number or a zero or jumping monkeys on the screen.

Comment: Printf after scanf avoids uninitialised value, but does not solve OPs first problem either.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's like I'm building an array from the ground up. Didn't think that my homemade array wouldn't be filled with anything. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of questions, for you to ask:

1. What if the user enters a negative value?
2. What if the user enters 0 ?
3. What if the user enters a very large value?
4. Did the array allocation succeed?
5. What is in my array after it is allocated?
6. If my array size is 0, will elemenArray[0] be valid?
7. Should I use a for loop, like everyonbe else does for walking through my array?

Just asking yourself these questions will fix this program in no time, and will get you through half of the next one you'll write.

Comment: Yes, quiestion # 5.

Comment: The second problem is answered by question #7.

Comment: OP wants to print "1" for first element. What do you think he means by that? I.e. I disagree.

Comment: OP wants to print the value entered by user in the line below the printf.  Not necessarily 1.  Right now he prints what we usually call garbage.  He will hopefully figure it out, once he's past the program crashing.

Comment: Well, we seem to have different guessed opinions on what OP wants. (I.e. I admit that mine is guessed, too. Sorry for not noticing earlier.) I made a comment to have OP clarify. Two actually.

Comment: My point is;  these are the same questions you yourself asked yourself  when reading this code.  Is stack overflow a place where students ask questions to move ahead, or is it a place where one gets his homework done for free?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146600/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-michael-roy).

Comment: OP, I recommend this answer in case this is a homework question. Seriously, in your own interest. (Just also use my very first comment, in case I guessed correctly on the meaning of "1".)

Comment: @Yunnosch and Michaël Roy-- I think that the concern over homework here is misplaced. This question is not a homework dump; OP has made a genuine effort in code that clearly shows some misunderstandings, and has asked a question. It is helpful to show correct code and best practices. OP can choose to use answers and advice however they choose.

Comment: @DavidBowling My impression also was not of homework. But Michael indicated having seen it repeatedly on a challenge site. So, asking OP for clarification seems appropriate.

Comment: I understand this may not be homework, but it is obvious OP is a student in learning, whether in a institution or by himself.  As to the list of questions, these are the same all programmers at any level ask.

Answer (score 1):

You have more problems than the fact that you print something else than the index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int elements = 0;
    printf("How many Elements will you enter? ");
    if((1!=scanf("%d", &elements))||(elements<1) ) // check return value, always a good idea
    {   printf("Reading number failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int* elementArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * elements);
    int i = 0;
    while ( (i<elements) // use the number you asked for to avoid writing beyond array
            && ((0==i) || (0 != elementArray[i-1]))) // stop when previously entered value is 0
    {
        printf("Element %d: ", i+1); // print the index
        // instead of the non-initialised value

        if(1!= scanf("%d", &elementArray[i]))
        {
            printf("Reading value failed!\n");
            free(elementArray); // cleanup
            return 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (i<elements)
    {
        printf("Stopped early because 0 was entered.\n");
    }
    free(elementArray);   

    return 0;
}
```